# AVL Tree rotation order

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

When there is an Imbalance and a Rotation is needed in an AVL tree, how do you go about picking which nodes to rotate first. In examples, sometimes I see the root node gets rotated first, sometimes I see a parent node get rotated first and sometimes a leaf node gets rotated first.

Comment: *"sometimes... sometimes... sometimes"*: this all depends on the tree. Please update your question and include concrete examples where the confusion arises and explain exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

With AVL trees, the imbalance caused by an insertion or deletion of a leaf will be detected as the balance factors are updated along the path from the leaf to root. As soon as a node is found (in that upwards traversal) that gets a balance factor that is out of range, either a single or double rotation will happen *at that node*. However, a double rotation breaks down into two single rotations, and the first of these two really acts on a child of the given node.